# Cannot find path of image in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I am using firebug to inspect an image in one of my companies Test sites. Some of the images have this path

`/CropUp/listnav/media/xxxxx.aaa`

```
xxx=ImageName
aaa=Extension
```

But the path it is giving does not exist? And from what I can see there are no virtual directories set up? What is going on here? Can any help?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a url rewrite happening..?
We do this for our imagegen images in order to have proper image extensions and other querystring configuration options whilst being transparent to the end user and seo-bots, etc..
Check to see if the images may be in the ~/media/ folder in your filesystem. That's where umbraco handled images and files are stored by default.

The only other thing i could suggest without any more info is to checkout [grepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) - it's a fantastic gui for windows answer to unixs regex searching - it's great for finding anything anywhere in the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you I will try out your suggestions